# click event for buttons in the google map info window

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to set up click events for buttons inside google marker infowindow so that when a user click "Get Direction" buttons, google route will show up ( it starts from the infowindow's address to user's current address) at the panel right beside the map.

Below is my code. If you click 'Get Direction' of store A, you will see a route show up at the panel right beside the map...

if I click other buttons, it says "
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at _.gg."

I currently stuck on the loop for these buttons... can someone give me some ideas?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Store Locations</title>

      <style>
        #map {
          width: 60%;
          height: 650px;
          margin-left: 4%;
          margin-top: 2%
        }

        #right-panel {
          font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
          line-height: 30px;
          height: 650px;
          float: right;
          width: 30%;
          overflow: auto;
          margin-top: 2%;
          height: 650px;
          margin-right: 4%;
        }

        @media print {
          #map {
            height: 650px;
            margin-left: 4%;
            width: 60%;
          }

          #right-panel {
            float: right;
            height: 650px;
          }
        }
      </style>

    </head>

    <p id='dTitle'>
      <h3>Store Locations</h3>
    </p>

    <div id="right-panel"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="directionsPanel"></div>



    <script>
      // 初始化map

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.0020285, -97.2347275), zoom: 4
        });
        var storeLocations = [
          { markerId: 1, title: 'Click for location details', LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(53.483710, -113.483230), contentString: '<div><strong>Store A</strong></div>' + '<p>div>Edmonton AB,  T6E 5C5, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button class="gDirection1">Get Directions</button></div>' },
          { markerId: 2, title: 'Click for location details', LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(50.036490, -110.667030), contentString: '<div><strong>Store B</strong></div>' + '<p><div>Medicine Hat AB,  T1A 2Z8, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button class="gDirection1">Get Directions</button></div>' },
          { markerId: 3, title: 'Click for location details', LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.262760, -123.004020), contentString: '<div><strong>Store C</strong></div>' + '<p><div>Burnaby BC, V5C 5T3, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button id="gDirection2">Get Directions</button></div>' }]

        var markers = []
        for (var i = 0; i < storeLocations.length; i++) {
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: storeLocations[i].LatLng,
            content: storeLocations[i].contentString,
            title: storeLocations[i].title
          });
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
            infowindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
            infowindow.set(this.title);
          });
        }

        function getCustomercurrentlocation() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              function (positionGet) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(positionGet.coords.latitude, positionGet.coords.longitude)),
                  map.setZoom(10)
                var contentcurrentLocation = '<h3><center>Your current location</h3></center>';
                var icon = {
                  url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(55, 55), // scaled size
                };
                var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  icon: icon,
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(positionGet.coords.latitude, positionGet.coords.longitude)
                });
                infowindow.setContent(contentcurrentLocation);
                infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
              },
              function (positionNotget) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(49.148160, -112.087260)),
                  map.setZoom(4)
              });
          }
          else // browser doesn't suppost Geolocation
            alert('Geolocation is not supported by your browser.');
        }

        //google.maps.event.addListener( "domready",getCustomercurrentlocation());

        var btns = document.getElementById("gDirection");
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
          btns.addListener('click', function calcRoute() {
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
            directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));
            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(49.148160, -112.087260);
            var end = new google.maps.LatLng(44.71682, -63.58431)
            var request = {
              origin: start,
              destination: end,
              travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
              if (status == 'OK') {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
              }
            });
          })


        }
        )



      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` on the line:

```
document.getElementById("gDirection").addEventListener('click',  function calcRoute(){
```

because there is no element in the DOM with `id="gDirection"`.

The button is defined like this:

```
<button class="gDirection">Get Directions</button>
```

To access that, you need to use `getElementsByClassName("gDirection")[0]`

(`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, notice the "s" on Element**s**).

In the code you posted, there will only ever be one `InfoWindow` open and in the DOM, so only the first element of that array will be needed.

Updated code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("gDirection")[0].addEventListener('click', function calcRoute() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(49.148160, -112.087260);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(44.71682, -63.58431)
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    console.log("origin="+request.origin.toUrlValue(6)+" dest="+request.destination.toUrlValue(6));
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
      }
    });
  })
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9pxL7a34/12/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map {
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-top: 2%
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 80%;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 650px;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

@media print {
  #map {
    height: 650px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 60%;
  }
  #right-panel {
    float: right;
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id='dTitle'>
  <h3>Store Locations</h3>
</p>

<div id="right-panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel"></div>

<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.0020285, -97.2347275),
      zoom: 4
    });
    var storeLocations = [{
        markerId: 1,
        title: 'Click for location details',
        LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(53.553429, -113.639793),
        contentString: '<div><strong>Store A</strong></div>' + '<p><<div>Edmonton AB, T5S 2T2, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button class="gDirection">Get Directions</div>'
      },
      {
        markerId: 2,
        title: 'Click for location details',
        LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(53.483710, -113.483230),
        contentString: '<div><strong>Store B</strong></div>' + '<p>div>Edmonton AB,  T6E 5C5, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button class="gDirection">Get Directions</button></div>'
      },
      {
        markerId: 3,
        title: 'Click for location details',
        LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(50.036490, -110.667030),
        contentString: '<div><strong>Store C</strong></div>' + '<p><div>Medicine Hat AB,  T1A 2Z8, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button class="gDirection">Get Directions</button></div>'
      },
      {
        markerId: 4,
        title: 'Click for location details',
        LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.262760, -123.004020),
        contentString: '<div><strong>Store D</strong></div>' + '<p><div>Burnaby BC, V5C 5T3, Canada</div></p>' + '<div><button class="gDirection">Get Directions</button></div>'
      }
    ]

    var markers = []
    for (var i = 0; i < storeLocations.length; i++) {
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: storeLocations[i].LatLng,
        content: storeLocations[i].contentString,
        title: storeLocations[i].title
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.content);
        infowindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
        infowindow.set(this.title);
      });
    }

    function getCustomercurrentlocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function(positionGet) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(positionGet.coords.latitude, positionGet.coords.longitude)),
              map.setZoom(10)
            var contentcurrentLocation = '<h3><center>Your current location</h3></center>';
            var icon = {
              url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(55, 55), // scaled size
            };
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(positionGet.coords.latitude, positionGet.coords.longitude)
            });
            infowindow.setContent(contentcurrentLocation);
            infowindow.open(map, newMarker);

          },
          function(positionNotget) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(49.148160, -112.087260)),
              map.setZoom(4)
          });
      } else // browser doesn't suppost Geolocation
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by your browser.');
    }

    //google.maps.event.addListener( "domready",getCustomercurrentlocation());

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("gDirection")[0].addEventListener('click', function calcRoute() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));
        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(49.148160, -112.087260);
        var end = new google.maps.LatLng(44.71682, -63.58431)
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };
        console.log("origin=" + request.origin.toUrlValue(6) + " dest=" + request.destination.toUrlValue(6));
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
          }
        });
      })
    })
  }
</script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```